# Why does this lambda [=] capture create several copies?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17

In the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

class tester {
public:
    tester() { 
        cout << "constructor\t" << this << "\n"; 
    }
    tester(const tester& other) { 
        cout << "copy cons.\t" << this << "\n"; 
    }
    ~tester() { 
        cout << "destructor\t" << this << "\n"; 
    }

    void print() const { 
        cout << "print\t\t" << this << "\n"; 
    }
};

int main() {
    tester t;

    cout << "  before lambda\n";
    thread t2([=] {
        cout << "  thread start\n";
        t.print();
        cout << "  thread end\n";
    });

    t2.join();
    cout << "  after join" << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled with `cl.exe` (on Windows) I get the following:

```
constructor 012FFA93
  before lambda
copy cons.  012FFA92
copy cons.  014F6318
destructor  012FFA92
  thread start
print       014F6318
  thread end
destructor  014F6318
  after join
destructor  012FFA93
```

And with `g++` (on WSL) I get:

```
constructor     0x7ffff5b2155e
  before lambda
copy cons.      0x7ffff5b2155f
copy cons.      0x7ffff5b21517
copy cons.      0x7fffedc630c8
destructor      0x7ffff5b21517
destructor      0x7ffff5b2155f
  thread start
print           0x7fffedc630c8
  thread end
destructor      0x7fffedc630c8
  after join
destructor      0x7ffff5b2155e
```

1. I would expect that the `[=]` capture would create exactly 1 copy of `tester`. Why are there several copies that are immediately destroyed?
2. Why the divergence between MSVC and GCC? Is this undefined behavior or something?

Comment: The lambda itself is passed around by value. So it gets copied together with its data members - including things it captured by value.

Comment: Whenever your lambda is copied, it also copies all the value captured objects. `std::thread` has to store the lambda in some way, which can involve copies. I believe a closure *could* move it's captured objects, but since you didn't provide a move constructor to your type then it is forced to be copied when it could be moved instead. If you add a move constructor you will probably see fewer copies.

Comment: Ah of course. When I provide a move constructor, the 2nd (and 3rd w/ GCC) copies turn into moves. The difference between the two compilers I'm guessing is just down to differences in copy elision?

Comment: @MHebes It becomes more clear, when you look at the lambda-structure working in the background: https://cppinsights.io/s/2c9bdb04

Comment: @SimonKraemer Wow, that's an awesome website. Thanks for the resource.

Comment: If someone wants to post an answer I'll mark it, thanks all.

Comment: g++ 9 in WSL gives that output, while g++ 10 (also in WSL) only copies twice. I suspect version 9 is missing out on an elision opportunity.

Comment: Could we use `std::ref` in order to prevent the copy done by passing the lambda by value ?

Comment: Ad2. Can't reproduce outcome for gcc: https://godbolt.org/z/nM8sn6hbx result is same as for MSVC. What version of gcc did you used and what are the compiler settings.

Comment: @MarekR as molbdnilo points out, I was using gcc 9.3. It's just the default packaged build-essentials with the WSL ubuntu box I'm running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard requires that the callable passed to the constructor for `std::thread` is effectively copy-constructible ([[thread.thread.constr]](https://eel.is/c++draft/thread.thread.class#thread.thread.constr-4))

> Mandates: The following are all true:
>
> - `is_­constructible_­v<decay_­t<F>, F>`
> - [...]

`is_­constructible_­v<decay_­t<F>, F>` is the same as `is_copy_constructible` (or rather, it's the other way around).

This is to allow implementations to freely pass around the callable until it reaches the point where it gets invoked. (In fact, the standard itself suggests the callable is copied at least once.)

Since a lambda is compiled into a small class with the function call operator overloaded (a *functor*), each time your lambda gets copied, it will create a copy of the captured `tester` instance.

If you do not wish for copying to happen, you can take a reference to your instance in the capture list instead:

```
thread t2([&ref = t] {
    cout << "  thread start\n";
    ref.print();
    cout << "  thread end\n";
});
```

### [Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/v7EzsjMfn)

#### Output:

```
constructor 0x7ffdfdf9d1e8
  before lambda
  thread start
print       0x7ffdfdf9d1e8
  thread end
  after join
destructor  0x7ffdfdf9d1e8
```